# Installing an extension in Magento 2 without having to run "setup:upgrade"

Tags: magento2, extensions

I need to install an extension **(Mailchimp for Magento 2)** on a website, but need to do it in a way that I won't need to run

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade.
```

Basically, the site was built by a developer long gone and has tons of problems, now running that upgrade command will require me to recompile with the command

```
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

which sometimes runs successfully and sometimes not, but always leaves the site in a broken state.

I have tried doing it via `composer` and the extension was added successfully, then the site broke after **upgrading/compiling**. I have not tried installing via the component manager because it requires the same upgrade command. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`setup:di:compile` is not necessarily to run unless your compilation is ON. you can turn it off by just removing `di.xml` file in the var folder. Now just try to run on `setup:upgrade` command and clear cache. See whether this works.

You can give a try in this way too. Try to define the module manually by mentioning about the same in  array of `config.php` path at `<root>/app/etc/config.php`. Here you can see an array with all the list of modules that are in your website. Add your module name in the list as `'Namespace_Module' => 1` for ex:  `'Magento_Store' => 1`. 
Now you need to enter your module details to database table `setup_module`. Check for the module version in the `module.xml` file of the module. Add the values accordingly to the table. 
Hopefully this should work.

Comment: I can't give it another shot until tomorrow. I'll give your suggestions a try and get back to you, thanks!

Comment: This one works great.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is always recommended to run setup:upgrade and you need to run di:compile after the new module to make the dependency Injection work without any issue.
2. di:compile may fail because of multiple reason you can try switch off / stop other resources like nginx/apache , php-fpm before compiling will give you some ram space that di:compile can occupy or increase your ram size. It is recommended not to compile on production environment, you can compile somwhere else and deploy the compiled files in production.
3. if you are working in a dev enviroment and don't want to break the website again and again and wait for the static:content:deploy to complete then use setup:upgrade --keep-generated.
4. Its also not recommended to delete di.xml from var folder.